# Simple Unit Conversion Program - scanf issues with do-while loop (C programming)

Tags: c, while-loop, scanf

The problem I am having currently is that the program does not follow through to the sections preceding the first scanf command and just skips the entire decision making process and returns to the beginning of the do-while loop. I have read up on other suggestions telling people to use fgetc() since the enter button after inputting your conversion type (1-5) creates an empty space in the input buffer and this would prevent that but I would really rather not since it is not part of my current learning material, as a last resort I shall use it, and even that I'm not sure how to implement in place of scanf. The program looks as if it is done, and translating this into c++ code (which I am familiar with) allows it to work, but for some reason it isn't cooperating with me in C code. I also tried another suggestion from stackoverflow which mentions using scanf as such: scanf("%c*c", &conversionDirection); which actually did allow it to go through to the next section but at times forces you to enter your decision twice, with the first input not giving you a reaction... I would really appreciate it if someone could test this code cause from here on out I am not sure what to do anymore, I've tried everything.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
    int userChoice;
    char conversionDirection;
    float calculateNumber;

    do
    {
        printf("Please enter one of the following: \n");
        printf("Number\tConversion\n\n");
        printf("1\t Kilogram/Pound\n");
        printf("2\t Litre/Gallon\n");
        printf("3\t Centimeter/Inch\n");
        printf("4\t Celsius/Fahrenheit\n");
        printf("5\t Quit\n");
        scanf("%d", &userChoice);

        if (userChoice == 1)
        {
            printf("Enter 'K' for Kilogram -> Pound or Enter 'P' for Pound -> Kilogram\n");
            scanf("%c", &conversionDirection);

            if (conversionDirection == 'K')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Kilograms\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Kilograms is equal to %f Pounds\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber * 2.2);
            }
            else if (conversionDirection == 'P')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Pounds\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Pounds is equal to %f Kilograms\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber / 2.2);
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 2)
        {
            printf("Enter 'L' for Litre -> Gallon or Enter 'G' for Gallon -> Litre\n");
            scanf("%c", &conversionDirection);

            if (conversionDirection == 'L')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Litres\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Liters is equal to %f Gallons\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber * 0.264172);
            }
            else if (conversionDirection == 'G')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Gallons\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Gallons is equal to %f Liters\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber / 0.264172);
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 3)
        {
            printf("Enter 'C' for Centimeter -> Inch or Enter 'I' for Inch -> Centimeter");
            scanf("%c", &conversionDirection);

            if (conversionDirection == 'C')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Centimeters\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Centimeters is equal to %f Inches\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber * 0.393701);
            }
            else if (conversionDirection == 'I')
            {
                printf("Please enter the amount of Inches\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f Inches is equal to %f Centimeters\n\n", calculateNumber, calculateNumber / 0.393701);
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 4)
        {
            printf("Enter 'C' for Celsius -> Fahrenheit or Enter 'F' for Fahrenheit -> Celsius");
            scanf("%c", &conversionDirection);

            if (conversionDirection == 'C')
            {
                printf("How many degrees Celsius?\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f degrees Celsius is equal to %f degrees Fahrenheit\n\n", calculateNumber, (calculateNumber * 9 / 5) + 32);
            }
            else if (conversionDirection == 'F')
            {
                printf("How many degrees Fahrenheit?\n");
                scanf("%f", &calculateNumber);

                printf("%f degrees Fahrenheit is equal to %f degrees Celsius\n\n", calculateNumber, (calculateNumber - 32) * 5 / 9);
            }
        }
        else if (userChoice == 5)
        {
            printf("Program Exit");
            return 0;
        }
        else
        {
            printf("Please enter a valid number");
        }
    } while (userChoice != 5);


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: That worked perfectly! Thank you so much. I'm new to this site and I'm not sure how to give you credit since you wrote a comment instead of an answer!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Two advices when using scanf (especially for numbers):

1) use `fflush(stdin);` before each call of scanf;

2) check the result of unputs - is number received or not?

For example, if you cannot work without correct input:

```cpp
do{
     printf("Please, enter number: ");
     fflush(stdin);
} while( 1 == scanf("%d", &number));
```

Comment: Your seond point is valid but `fflush()` is for output streams, (although *may* work on inputs).